# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageai'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am tring to install the object detection or imageai for python in Pycharm. I did all the installation method but this shows me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageai'`

---

This is my code

```
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
import os
execution_path = os.getcwd()


prediction = ImagePrediction()
prediction.setModelTypeAsResNet()
prediction.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5"))
prediction.loadModel()


predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(os.path.join(execution_path, "1.jpg"), result_count=5 )
for eachPrediction, eachProbability in zip(predictions, probabilities):
    print(eachPrediction , " : " , eachProbability)
```

What do I need to do to fix it?
I am new to python please help me.

---

the output

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python37/files/FirstPrediction/FirstPrediction.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageai'
```

---

```
C:\Users\משתמש>pip show imageai
Name: imageai
Version: 2.0.2
Summary: A flexible Computer Vision and Deep Learning library for applications and systems.
Home-page: https://moses.specpal.science
Author: Moses Olafenwa and John Olafenwa
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: MIT
Location: c:\python37\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

---

```
C:\Users\משתמש>pip -V
pip 18.1 from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: How did you install the `imageai` module? using `pip` ?

Comment: To add to the question above: in which terminal? The one embedded in pycharm or the one of the system?
Most secure way of doing this when you begin is by using the Pycharm terminal that directly installs the module in the environment set for the project.

Comment: Also, in which environment are you using? If it is conda/venv then you will need to change it  in "project interpreter settings" in pycharm.

Comment: I using pip to install and my project on pycharm

Comment: @MehranTorki  yes I use pip

Comment: @smm I don’t understand what I need to do can you make an example

Comment: have you solved this problem even i face same @עמיתלוינזון

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terensflow didn’t support Python 3.7 need to download python 3.6 uninstall python 3.7 and install all with python 3.6

Answer (score 5):

Your First need to download this ImageAI whl file and from here.
https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/2.0.2/imageai-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl

Run following

```
pip install imageai-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: This is actually very useful in case you need to install offline. You download first then install locally from the whl file itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can install **ImageAI** directly from PyPi

```
pip3 install imageai --upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.